# Xcode Swift, Keyframe animation has unwanted delay between animations loops on a bezier curve

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

Im attempting to animate a UIView along an oval using a bezier curve. The code works except that there is a delay between each loop of the animation. I'm at a loss as to what is causing this.

```
let myView = UIView()
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 30, height: 30)
        
let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        
let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.path = path.cgPath
animation.repeatCount = 1000
animation.duration = 1
        
myView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "animate along path")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. The pause between animation loops only takes place when making a path with the UIBezierPath(ovalIn:) constructor. There's no delay when manually making your own path. So I made my own oval.

Replaced this

```
let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
```

with this

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        
let path = UIBezierPath()
        
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
```